# Read it in the comment section below/given below

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs

As we know that the word **below** acts as an **adverb and preposition.**

Sentences:

> Read it in the comment section **below.**

> Read it in the comment section **given below.**

Are they both correct? Explain.

Comment: Yes, when you refer to things in a text below some point, below comes after the noun, not before it. It is an adverb, not a noun. "read it the section below"

Comment: "below" is correct. "given below" is incorrect, because whoever is posting this did not "give" the comment section.

Answer (score -1):

The latter implies that you have somehow been given the comment section instead of it simply appearing where it is. "Given below" is used when something is supplied to you, like a periodic table printed on a chemistry test